# AlarmManager: new alarms not set/triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I have an application where there is an option to set a reminder at a certain time each day. The problem is that for some users, they never get the reminder. I have some logging then the application starts, and for them the alarm is not set, even if it should be.

Only some users have this problem and I can't reproduce it myself and I can't see what the error is!

I set the reminder like this:

```
fun scheduleReminder(context: Context, reschedule: Boolean = false) {
    val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    val alarmPendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
    }

    // Get the time from the settings, LocalTime
    val time = getReminderTime(context = context)
    val diff = kotlin.math.abs(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(time, LocalTime.now()).toInt())

    // If the time is before current time, not far in the future or if it's from previous
    // triggered alarm, schedule next alarm for tomorrow
    val shouldSetForTomorrow = diff < 30 || time < LocalTime.now() || reschedule
    val calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().apply {
        if (shouldSetForTomorrow)
            add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)

        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time.hour)
        set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.minute)
        set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31)
        alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, alarmPendingIntent)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, alarmPendingIntent)
    else
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, alarmPendingIntent)
}
```

To get the reminder time:

```
fun getReminderTime(context: Context): LocalTime {
    val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("reminder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    val secondsOfDay = sharedPref.getInt(REMINDER_TIME, 0)
    val hours = secondsOfDay / 3600
    val minutes = (secondsOfDay - 3600 * hours) / 60

    return LocalTime.of(hours, minutes)
}
```

The receiver looks like

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        scheduleReminder(context = context, true)
        showReadReminderNotification(context = context)
    }
}
```

I also have a boot receiver:

```
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {
            scheduleReminder(context = context)
        }
    }
}
```

And the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.lostpixels.biblept.notifications.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true"/>

<receiver android:name="com.lostpixels.biblept.notifications.BootReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have compared with several other posts at Stackoverflow, but I can't see what the problem is.

Each time the app starts I check the reminder like this, if the alarm is set and if the shared preferences has info that a reminder should be set, but for many users, this log is triggered, that no alarm has been set even if it should be.

```
if (!isReminderSet(context = this) && userWantsReminder(context = this)) {
    Log("MainActivity", "Reminder not set when it should be")
    scheduleReminder(context = this)
}

fun userWantsReminder(context: Context): Boolean {
    return context.getSharedPreferences("reminder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        .getBoolean(REMINDER_SET, false)
}

fun isReminderSet(context: Context): Boolean {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, 0,
        Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
    ) != null
}
```

Can anyone spot what the error is, since I certainly can't. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a permission issue?

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: That is true, I did forget to add that permission! I will ask affected users if they reboot their phone often. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I've got some feedback from users and they say that they have not rebooted their phones for weeks or more, but get this error every day when they start the app, that the reminder was not set. So it must be some other problem unfortunately. :/